# How do I return which delimiter split a certain string? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm splitting a user input `string` at the *math operators*, I want to know if there's some way to remember exactly which *operator* acted as the *delimiter* within the code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userInput = textBox1.Text;
    char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
    //splits the entered string into substrings after encountering operator characters
    string[] operands = userInput.Split(operators);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *tokenizing* instead of *splitting* (in the simplest case you can use `Regex.Split` instead of `string.Split`):

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string userInput = textBox1.Text;
  char[] operators = { '+', '-', '*', '/' };
  
  string pattern = "(" + string.Join("|", operators
    .Select(c => Regex.Escape(c.ToString()))) + ")";

  string[] tokens = Regex.Split(userInput, pattern);
```

If `textBox1.Text == "5 * 6 + 7"`, `tokens` will be `{"5 ", "*", "6", "+", "7"}`. All you have to do now is to check for each `token` if it's *operation* or *operand*. Something like this:

```
  // {"5", "6", "7"}
  string[] operands = tokens
    .Where(token => !operators.Any(op => op.ToString() == token))
    .Select(item => item.Trim())
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    .ToArray();

  // {"*", "+"}
  string[] operations = tokens
    .Where(token => operators.Any(op => op.ToString() == token))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: thanks for using `Regex.Escape`

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this.